# I can SSH/HTTP to my server but can't ping it

Tags: linux, networking, server

I had a Raspberry Pi set up as a web server on my home DSL line. Everything was fine. Recently i sent my Pi to a friend because he had a better connection that i could use. I got the static internal ip, DMZ set up. Everything works fine as far as i can see but i can't ping the server, although i can reach the site and mumble server that i host on it. I use duckdns to resolve his dynamic ip, i tried pinging the ip address directly but that didnt work either. My iptables configurations are nonexistent, iptables -L doesn't show any rules set. I didn't need them when Pi was at my house, simply setting it as a DMZ server was enough. I checked the firewall settings of my friends router and it is not enabled. I am no expert in networking or server management, so i dont know which information i should provide in order you to come up with a solution. If anybody asks for something in particular, i will edit it in. Thank you all in advance.

Hardware: Raspberry Pi 2
OS: Raspbian

My /etc/network/interfaces file(which i used to set the static ip)

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.44
gateway 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

Comment: as this question has nothing to do with development, it would better be asked on [su] or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not unheard of, that an ISP (yours, your friend's) blocks ICMP-requests (aka `ping`).

you could use a "TCP ping" on a given port, with a tool like `nmap` instead.
e.g. the following will check whether the  is reachable via port 80:

```
nmap -sn -PS80 <ip>
```

Comment: so it's not an actual problem, that i should be worried about?

Comment: no. these days many w32 machines block ICMP-requests by default. it has become bog standard, and you shouldn't make assumptions on not being able to ping (unless of course you control the entire network in question)